# Is it possible to store hidden fields in Passes? (iOS 6.0 Passbook JSON)

Tags: ios, json, passbook

I want to store hidden values in the JSON file, which aren't displayed in the passbook, but can be accessed from my app after I loaded my passes like this:

```
[_pass localizedValueForFieldKey:@"hidden_field_1"]
```

Comment: Since the passes will always be created and signed on a server, why not store the additional data server side and either bring it back when you fetch the .pkpass bundle, or poll the server for the latest data on demand.  FWIW, I have fond that Passbook ignores additional fields in pass.json - have you actually tried what you have suggested above?

Answer (score 1):

Since the pass serial format is arbitrary, you it might work for you to append the (short) data to it.

```
normal serial          serial with data

00001                  00001|laskjfrg645sa
00002                  00002|a654sf6s54fas64
00002                  00003|a6sd5f4a46sdf5
```

As you are in control of the "id" part, the serial will always remain unique.

Anyway, while it probably works, it's not very *kosher*.

Comment: That would be a great solution, but in this particular case I have some crypted data broken into 2 pieces, and for the security reasons I want to store the first piece on the server and the second on the device.

Answer (score 0):

According to my reading of [Passbook Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Introduction.html) all fields are displayed. Users are supposed to know what is being stored in the pass so they aren't afraid to accept it. You might consider using the backFields to store a encrypted string with a label that says something like "Verification tracking field".

Answer (score 0):

With the new iOS 7.0 API it is possible with the userInfo key.
For more information, read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW1)